# How to fix overflow error when calling macros

Tags: excel, vba

Im getting an overflow error when I call my macros. When I run them individually, it is fine, but when I call them one after the other, I get an error. First one imports the data and then the second macro does a small analysis of the imported data on a seperate sheet.

First Macro

```
Sub ImportFiles()

    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim total As Integer
    Dim intChoice As Integer
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook

    'allow the user to select multiple files
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = True
    'make the file dialog visible to the user
    intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'determine what choice the user made
    If intChoice <> 0 Then
        'get the file path selected by the user
        For i = 1 To Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems.Count
            strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(i)

            Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath)

            For Each sheet In wbSource.Worksheets
                total = wbNew.Worksheets.Count
                wbSource.Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy _
                after:=wbNew.Worksheets(total)
            Next sheet

            wbSource.Close
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Second Macro (error in dataRow = dataRow + 1)

```
Sub Analysis()

Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
Dim thisSheet As Worksheet
Dim thisWorkbook As Workbook

Set thisWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set thisSheet = ActiveSheet

For i = 1 To thisWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    If Not thisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name = thisSheet.Name Then

        Set dataSheet = thisWorkbook.Sheets(i)

    End If

Next i



If thisWorkbook.Sheets.Count >= 2 Then

    'dataSheet now contains the sheet we need to pull data from.
    Dim summaryRow(1 To 7) As Integer
    Dim dataRow As Integer

    dataRow = 1

    summaryRow(1) = 10
    summaryRow(2) = 13
    summaryRow(3) = 16
    summaryRow(4) = 19
    summaryRow(5) = 22
    summaryRow(6) = 28
    summaryRow(7) = 31

    For i = 1 To UBound(summaryRow)

        Do While Not dataSheet.Range("U" & dataRow) = "Nominal"
            dataRow = dataRow + 1 'ERROR HERE
        Loop

        dataRow = dataRow + 1

        thisSheet.Range("I" & summaryRow(i)) = dataSheet.Range("U" & dataRow)
        If Not dataSheet.Range("AH" & (dataRow + 1)) = "" Then
            thisSheet.Range("J" & summaryRow(i)) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(dataSheet.Range("AH" & (dataRow + 1) & ":" & "AH" & (dataRow + 7)), "=" & "PASS")
            thisSheet.Range("K" & summaryRow(i)) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(dataSheet.Range("AH" & (dataRow + 1) & ":" & "AH" & (dataRow + 7)), "=" & "EVALUATE")
            thisSheet.Range("L" & summaryRow(i)) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(dataSheet.Range("AH" & (dataRow + 1) & ":" & "AH" & (dataRow + 7)), "=" & "FAIL")
        Else
            thisSheet.Range("J" & summaryRow(i)) = "N/A"
            thisSheet.Range("K" & summaryRow(i)) = "N/A"
            thisSheet.Range("L" & summaryRow(i)) = "N/A"
        End If

    Next i


End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Change all of your `As Integer` to `As Long` - the limit on integer is ~32k, which is pretty low if you're dealing with large datasets.

Comment: ThisWorkbook is a reserved name (workbook where this vba code resides)

Answer (score 0):

Likely you can break it at the first execution if you run the second Macro to test an excel sheet where the "Nominal" values is never set, in that case the following will generate an infinite loop that will break as soon as the maximum value for the integer dataRow is reached.
        Do While Not dataSheet.Range("U" & dataRow) = "Nominal"
            dataRow = dataRow + 1 'ERROR HERE
        Loop
You could probably avoid the error by using a for instead of do while which is based on a pre-computed number of row or a max set as constraint.
I do not have Office on my netbook but I am pretty sure the following logic is not going to crash, except for some silly syntax mistakes I could have done.

```
Sub Analysis()

Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
Dim thisSheet As Worksheet
Dim thisWorkbook As Workbook

Set thisWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set thisSheet = ActiveSheet

For i = 1 To thisWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    If Not thisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name = thisSheet.Name Then

        Set dataSheet = thisWorkbook.Sheets(i)

    End If

Next i



If thisWorkbook.Sheets.Count >= 2 Then

    'dataSheet now contains the sheet we need to pull data from.
    Dim summaryRow(1 To 7) As Integer
    Dim dataRow As Integer

    Dim bfound as boolean
    ''dataRow = 1

    summaryRow(1) = 10
    summaryRow(2) = 13
    summaryRow(3) = 16
    summaryRow(4) = 19
    summaryRow(5) = 22
    summaryRow(6) = 28
    summaryRow(7) = 31

    For i = 1 To UBound(summaryRow)

       bfound=false
       For dataRow = 1 to 2147000000
            If dataSheet.Range("U" & dataRow) = "Nominal" Then
                    bfound=true
                    exit for
            End If
    Next

        If bfound Then
            dataRow = dataRow + 1
            thisSheet.Range("I" & summaryRow(i)) = dataSheet.Range("U" & dataRow)
            If Not dataSheet.Range("AH" & (dataRow + 1)) = "" Then
                thisSheet.Range("J" & summaryRow(i)) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(dataSheet.Range("AH" & (dataRow + 1) & ":" & "AH" & (dataRow + 7)), "=" & "PASS")
                thisSheet.Range("K" & summaryRow(i)) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(dataSheet.Range("AH" & (dataRow + 1) & ":" & "AH" & (dataRow + 7)), "=" & "EVALUATE")
                thisSheet.Range("L" & summaryRow(i)) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(dataSheet.Range("AH" & (dataRow + 1) & ":" & "AH" & (dataRow + 7)), "=" & "FAIL")
            Else
                thisSheet.Range("J" & summaryRow(i)) = "N/A"
                thisSheet.Range("K" & summaryRow(i)) = "N/A"
                thisSheet.Range("L" & summaryRow(i)) = "N/A"
            End If
        Else
           '' I do not have idea what you want to do in this case
        End if
    Next i


End If

End Sub
```